# Making a shell script run as a daemon at boot

Tags: linux, bash, shell, ubuntu

I have a shell script ( bash ) which I am currently running in the background to test it. Now I want to run it as a daemon after booting the computer. How can I achieve this? It already has an infinite loop because it will be running till the computer is switched off.

Comment: `/etc/rc.d` will help you. Add `/path/to/your/script&`. If you want a real full daemon, you'll need to provide proper scripts in `/etc/init.d`

Comment: thanks, will try it out and how to give root permissions to it once and for all?

Answer (score 2):

Put the full path into the script into the **/etc/rc.local** file before the **exit 0** line.

Answer (score 1):

Or you can soft link to your script from inside `/etc/init.d`. It should be executed with root permissions.